# what is the difference between navigator "object" And Navigator "Function" in browser console

Tags: javascript, browser

I have searched the web for an answer but all links talk about navigator object.

[image: Screen shot of browser console]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `navigator`, you're accessing the `window.navigator` property, which returns an instance of [the `Navigator` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) representing the current browser state.

The `Navigator` function is the constructor for that object, but it's implementation dependent, hence it being shown as native code.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. When I call the function it always threw an exception "Illegal constructor" where do you think I can find the definition for appropriate constructor

Comment: So can we do everything using window.navigator ? is there any reason for us to access Navigator for any purpose ?